# Google geomap with jquery fails in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, google-maps

I faced with problem that geomap by google fails with JQuery together in Internet explorer.

Otherwise in Firefox it looks like this:

[image: 1239617014-clip-11kb]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1239617014-clip-11kb.jpg))</sub>

Here comes js references

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABCDEFG">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ui.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image: 1239620705-clip-21kb]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1239620705-clip-21kb.png))</sub>

Please anybody help with this...

Thanks in advise.

Comment: What's the error? How does it fail?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have edited my post and add snapshot of the error

Comment: I have accordion (ui) on the page, and when I removed them from page, all works fine. But It's needed there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing JQuery.UI.Dialog from page.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug javascript in IE, but it's even harder to debug without the actual url, or when using minified javascript.  You might want to switch to the full non-minified version of jquery temporarily, so that you can find the line where the error occurs and see what's going on.

Also, in firefox you can try using firebug to see if it throws any errors.  Even though the map is working in firefox, it may be silently recovering from an error that IE can't recover from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a console.log() call to print to firebug? This will cause IE to throw errors. If thats the case maybe try something like this

```
var a = "hello";
try
{
console.log(a);
}
catch(err)
{
alert(a);
}
```

this will substitute the console.log with a plain old alert in IE

Answer (score 0):

```
#map { float:left; width:700px; height:500px; margin-top:10px; }
```

That's all :-)